# How to run this portion of code?

Tags: java, interpreter

i found this snippet of code on stack and i wanted to try it out on my machine but it keeps giving me an error of

Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

can anyone help me figure out what to do?
This is the portion of the code i wanted to try on my machine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
public int parse(String input) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

            return consumeLine(scanner);
        }

        public int consumeLine(Scanner scanner) {
            if( scanner.hasNext("(") ) {
                return consumeExpression(scanner);

            } else if( scanner.hasNext("IF") ) {
                return consumeIf(scanner);
            }
            return 0;
        }


        public int consumeExpression(Scanner scanner) {
            scanner.next("(");
            int a = scanner.nextInt();
            int b = scanner.nextInt();
            String op = scanner.next("[+-/*]");
            scanner.next(")");

            if( "+".equals(op) ) {
                return a + b;

            } else if( "-".equals(op) ) {
                return a - b;
            } 

            throw new RuntimeException("parsing error");
        }

        public int consumeIf(Scanner scanner) {
            scanner.next("IF");
            int exp1 = consumeExpression(scanner);
            int exp2 = consumeExpression(scanner);
            int exp3 = consumeExpression(scanner);
            int exp4 = consumeExpression(scanner);

            if( exp1 < 0 ) {
                return exp2;
            } else if( exp1 == 0 ) {
                return exp3;
            } 

            throw new RuntimeException("should not be here (TM)");
        }
```

Comment: do exactly as the error says `Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)`  research how to make a basic java application

Comment: ive already added the public static void main(String[] args) but not quite sure what to put in it to make it run

Comment: where?  I can not see it

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit it, but after i added the main im not quite sure how to call the function to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    public int parse(String input) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        return consumeLine(scanner);
    }

    public int consumeLine(Scanner scanner) {
        if( scanner.hasNext("\\(") ) {
            return consumeExpression(scanner);
        } else if( scanner.hasNext("IF") ) {
            return consumeIf(scanner);
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public int consumeExpression(Scanner scanner) {
        scanner.next("\\(");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        String op = scanner.next("[+-/*]");
        scanner.next("\\)");

        if( "+".equals(op) ) {
            return a + b;

        } else if( "-".equals(op) ) {
            return a - b;
        } 

        throw new RuntimeException("parsing error");
    }

    public int consumeIf(Scanner scanner) {
        scanner.next("IF");
        int exp1 = consumeExpression(scanner);
        int exp2 = consumeExpression(scanner);
        int exp3 = consumeExpression(scanner);
        int exp4 = consumeExpression(scanner);

        if( exp1 < 0 ) {
            return exp2;
        } else if( exp1 == 0 ) {
            return exp3;
        } 

        throw new RuntimeException("should not be here (TM)");
    }
```

sample output

```
System.out.println(parse(" IF ( 0 0 - ) ( 1 1 + ) ( 2 2 + ) ( 3 3 + )"));
// -> 4
```

Comment: i get an error with parse when i try to use that in the main

Comment: nvm i got it to work, but im trying to figure out how this code works and why can someone explain to me which part of the code is the operand part? im trying to see if i can make it so it works like (+ 3 3)